# How can I get the provider object from a wallet object in ethersjs?

Tags: ethers.js

How can I get the `provider` from a `Wallet` when using ethersjs?

I have tried getting the provider through `wallet.provider` but this is different from the Ethereum provider which has the `send` method.

I have also tried the following:

```
const network = await wallet.provider.getNetwork();
const provider = new providers.JsonRpcProvider(network);
```

The `JsonRpcProvider` in this case should return a provider object which has the `send` method that is different from  `wallet.provider`. However, the above still doesn't work because I'm not sure how I can convert from the wallet to the provider without losing any information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your wallet is connected to the provider you should be able to get the providers object using `wallet.provider`

if you are trying to access the send function of the provider try creating a provider with JsonRpcProvider like:

- create a provider with `new ethers. providers.JsonRpcProvider(<networkUrl>)`
- but I guess this send function is used to fetch blockchain with raw data

if you are trying to send transaction using ethers provider directly.
use `provider.sendTransaction(<signedTransaction>)`
this will send your signed Transaction to blockchain

Comment: Am I able to get the `netowrkUrl` from `wallet.provider`? As much as possible, I'm trying to convert whatever wallet information provided by the user into the `Provider` object.

Comment: wallet and provider are two different things. provider only determines which network you are connected to. whereas wallet can be connected to any network so, you should always have a wallet connected to a provider/network your app is working on.

so, if your wallet is not connected with provider- wallet.provider will be null.
and to create a provider networkUrl is the gateway to blockchain network. in case on ethereum you can get it from infura like services

Comment: So does it mean even if a wallet is connected to a provider, I won’t be able to get the `networkUrl` of the provider from `wallet.provider`? This could be useful because if I could get the `networkUrl` from the wallet’s provider, I could then pass it into `JsonRpcProvider` with something like this: `new ethers.providers.JsonRpcProvider(wallet.provider.networkUrl)`

Answer (score 0):

```
const provider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider( window.ethereum, "any" );
const network = await provider.getNetwork();
const chainId = network.chainId;
```